# Apache Spark RDD cache and Lineage confusion

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I fill an RDD with some random math values:

```
val itemFactors = rddItems.mapValues(newFactors => 
    Vector(Array.fill(2){math.random})
)
```

I then join that RDD to some other RDD and cache it:

```
val finalRDD = itemFactors.join(rddItemsUsers).map{
    case(itemid, (itemVector, ((userid, rating), userVector))) => 
        (itemid, itemVector, userid, userVector, rating)}.cache
```

I then perform a calculation on the data held in the `finalRDD`:

```
sqrt(finalRDD.aggregate(0.0)((accum, item) => 
    accum + pow(item._5 - item._4.dot(item._2), 2), _ + _) / finalRDD.count)
```

I call the final part of the code, `sqrt(...)` repeatedly from the console and every single time I get a different result - which is not desired as I haven't changed anything! This can be remedied (i.e. made so I get a consistent result) in 2 ways:

- Instead of initialising `itemFactors` with `math.random`, I can fill the Array with a fixed number, e.g. 1.0
- I can do `itemFactors.cache`.

Now, I understand that due to lineage, every time `itemFactors` is called it will call `math.random` and create a new number - this will therefore affect my calculation when it's performed. This is why using a fixed number when filling the Array produces consistent result.

But, the big problem and the bit which I don't understand is: I am caching `finalRDD` which is what the calculation is performed on, and as it comprises of `itemFactors`, surely it shouldn't matter what `itemFactor`'s Array is filled with as the node is only visited once? I thought I was beginning to get a grasp on the lineage; however, this has just thrown me.

Comment: `cache()` doesn't guarantee it's always cached -- for example do you have enough memory to hold it? what is it's % cached? it's also recomputed if, say, you lose a block.

Comment: Not too sure how to check, but I checked `getStorageLevel` and I get:
`StorageLevel(false, true, false, true, 1)`. If I do `getStorageLevel.description` I get: `Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated`. `getStorageLevel.useMemory` returns `True`

Comment: Can you make it a reproducible example? I don't know what's in `rddItems` and `rddItemsUsers`. Could be gnomes.

Comment: You can check the fraction cached on the storage tab of the UI.

Comment: I'll make a reproducible example asap. Thank you for the UI hint.

Comment: Did you figure it out? :)
I am having the same doubt

Answer (score 3):

If your cache is not able to fit in memory, it is lost based on LRU policy.

To avoid that you can use persist which take arguments as shown

```
val result = input.map(x => x*x)
result.persist(MEMORY_ONLY)
```

**MEMORY_ONLY** - Store RDD as deserialized Java objects in the JVM. If the RDD does not fit in memory, some partitions will not be cached and will be recomputed on the fly each time they're needed. This is the default level.

**MEMORY_AND_DISK** Store RDD as deserialized Java objects in the JVM. If the RDD does not fit in memory, store the partitions that don't fit on disk, and read them from there when they're needed.

**MEMORY_ONLY_SER** Store RDD as serialized Java objects (one byte array per partition). This is generally more space-efficient than deserialized objects, especially when using a fast serializer, but more CPU-intensive to read.

**MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER** Similar to MEMORY_ONLY_SER, but spill partitions that don't fit in memory to disk instead of recomputing them on the fly each time they're needed.

**DISK_ONLY**   Store the RDD partitions only on disk.
MEMORY_ONLY_2, MEMORY_AND_DISK_2, etc.  Same as the levels above, but replicate each partition on two cluster nodes.

**OFF_HEAP** (experimental) Store RDD in serialized format in Tachyon. Compared to MEMORY_ONLY_SER, OFF_HEAP reduces garbage collection overhead and allows executors to be smaller and to share a pool of memory, making it attractive in environments with large heaps or multiple concurrent applications. Furthermore, as the RDDs reside in Tachyon, the crash of an executor does not lead to losing the in-memory cache. In this mode, the memory in Tachyon is discardable. Thus, Tachyon does not attempt to reconstruct a block that it evicts from memory.

[Refer to this link for more documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#which-storage-level-to-choose)